# Join differently depending on conditions

Tags: sql-server, join, conditional-statements

I have a join and I would like to take into account the case where 'LASTAvenant.CodeAvenant' = 0 :

```
FROM Avenant BeforeLastAvenant
JOIN Avenant LASTAvenant ON LASTAvenant.CodeContrat =
BeforeLastAvenant.CodeContrat AND LASTAvenant.CodeAvenant > 0
                            AND LASTAvenant.CodeAvenant - 1 = BeforeLast.CodeAvenant
```

I am using this join to compare the values in LASTAvenant and BeforeLastAvenant so the condition '>0' makes sense (avoiding -1 after).

Given this I won't be able to reach the 'CodeAvenant' = 0 but I want to compare it with the previous version of itself from a History table.
Depending on the 'CodeAvenant' I want to join on History table or the LASTAvenant table.

I would like to do something like:

```
JOIN Avenant LASTAvenant ON LASTAvenant.CodeContrat = 
BeforeLastAvenant.CodeContrat AND IF LASTAvenant.CodeAvenant = 0 
                                  THEN ( --here comes the tricky part I want to replace the 
--table
                                  'BeforeLastAvenant.CodeAvenant = HistorytableAvenant.CodeAvenant'
                                       )
                             ELSE  LASTAvenant.CodeAvenant =  BeforeLastAvenant.CodeAvenant
```

I tried to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your case correctly  this is what you want . Try with this

```
JOIN Avenant LASTAvenant ON LASTAvenant.CodeContrat = BeforeLastAvenant.CodeContrat
and BeforeLastAvenant.CodeAvenant = HistorytableAvenant.CodeAvenant
where LASTAvenant.CodeAvenant = 0 

union all

JOIN Avenant LASTAvenant ON LASTAvenant.CodeContrat = BeforeLastAvenant.CodeContrat
and LASTAvenant.CodeAvenant - 1 =  BeforeLastAvenant.CodeAvenant
where LASTAvenant.CodeAvenant <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks that is I am trying since I've posted. But unfortunately my sql request is more complex I thought I could make it more simple. In fact my HistoryTable has one column more than the others I cannot join directly but select all the columns ecxept one. So your solution should work.

Answer (score 1):

One solution: With `UNION ALL` you can add the history records with `CodeAvenant = 0` as `CodeAvenant = -1` records:

```
FROM Avenant LASTAvenant
JOIN
(
  SELECT CodeContrat, CodeAvenant, <other columns>
  FROM Avenant
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CodeContrat, -1 AS CodeAvenant, <other columns>
  FROM HistorytableAvenant
  WHERE CodeAvenant = 0
) BeforeLastAvenant ON  BeforeLastAvenant.CodeContrat = LASTAvenant.CodeContrat
                    AND BeforeLastAvenant.CodeAvenant = LASTAvenant.CodeAvenant - 1;
```